# What do you have to do to see the craters names in Google maps for the planets in the solar system?

Tags: google-maps

I want to see the craters names for the planets in the solar system just like in this video

[Mercury planet 3d Google maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8Eb5hnMjQg)

However, when I go here [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps/space/mercury/@2.544644,11.7235166,806540m/data=!3m1!1e3) , no labels appear. I believe it's the correct link, but I dont see many options others than zoom in and out, 2d or 3d view, etc.

What do you have to do to see the craters names in Google maps for the planets in the solar system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to be signed-in your Google account**.

When not signed in you can not see the names. 
Once signed-in they magically appear :)

Comment: Pretty nice. Isn't it?